# Mongoose: Querying date field inside an array

Tags: mongoose

I have a mongo collection for the which the docs look like this:

```
{
  id: 'id',
  patches: [ {
      id: 'patchId',
      timestamp: 'patchTimestamp' }
  ]
}
```

For a given id, I want to find all the patches greater than a given date. I have tried this with $elemMatch, but for some reason that does not seem to be working (the results are not correct). For sake of completeness, here's the query I wrote:

```
{ patches: { $elemMatch: { timestamp: { $gt: givenDate } } } }
```

Any help on this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Please try this

{ patches: { $elemMatch: { timestamp: { $gt: new Date(givenDate) } } } }